# Use iXGuard for Enterprise distribution

Tags: ios, obfuscation, enterprise-distribution, ixguard

I'm trying to use iXGuard to obfuscate an app that's going to be distributed using Enterprise Distribution.
Obviously, our Apple Developer Account doesn't have access to App Store Connect, so we can't create iOS App Store Distribution certificates. Thus, we cannot export our app for App Store (as mentioned in the manuals).

But Enterprise Distribution also has the option to compile for Bitcode. However, iXGuard doesn't seem to recognize Bitcode in an Enterprise IPA.

Is there any solution to use iXGuard with Enterprise distribution?

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps you should contact [Guardsquare support](https://www.guardsquare.com/en/support)?

Comment: Already did that, figured maybe asking here would be faster.

Comment: Did you get any solution for this from GuardSquare?

Comment: You can run iXguard on the XCArchive file, and normally export the IPA from the archive using Organizer. I don't remember the exact parameter for the `ixguard` command line tool however.

Answer (score 1):

Just to put my comment as an answer to this:

You can run `ixguard` on an `XCArchive` file and export an IPA from the obfuscated XCArchive. You need to pass an argument to the command line tool (it is either `-archive` or `-xcarchive`, I don't have access to the docs now).

And then, you can export an obfuscated IPA from the obfuscated XCArchive.

Please note that App Store Review generally doesn't accept obfuscated apps unless it's for very specific business requirements, like a mobile banking app.